# Notepad++ Copy word from start of line to end of line

Tags: notepad

I've looked all over the net for 2 days but don't seem to be able to find the answer. I have a huge list..

Fr example

apple orange

This is what I am trying to end up with..I simply want to copy the first word only (whatever that may be) onto the end

apple orange:apple

I cannot find a way of copying the first word only without the white-space to the end. I have worked out how to put the : onto the end of all the lines (`find $ replace with :`)

I have tried doing .* to cut everything after the first word out and save the list then add it back on using another tool but it goes out of line.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use replace module (Ctrl+H) in NP++, here's the inputs :

Find what : `^([\w\-\']+)(.*)`
Replace with : `\1\2:\1`
Search mode :"Regular expression"

Replace expr can be optimized.

Comment: If you use \w\-, that will only include alphanumeric characters, underscores, and the hyphen character. It will miss out other punctuation characters which might be present in the first word, for example apostrophes.

Comment: Right, it's one of the edge cases not checked.